# Are certain node objects inheriting from two classes?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node [guide](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/), it says that:

> "The request object that's passed in to a handler implements the
>   ReadableStream interface."

However, afterwards it also says that

> "Note: The request object is an instance of IncomingMessage.".

So how is `request` also instance of IncomingMessage and also it implements RedableStream interface?
How would you achieve that in JS?
Also, I thought in JS there were no interfaces?

Comment: Perhaps have a read of the source code if you want to learn more and understand deeper? https://github.com/nodejs/readable-stream

Comment: @timothyclifford not bad but since I am not very experienced JS developer I thought someone could break it down here a bit or just explain "some" basics of how things I mentioned are done in node.

Comment: An object can both "implement" and "be an instance of" something. The interface is for the documentation, not a real thing.

Comment: @elclanrs in JS right? Can you link to some material about parts of JS which are used to achieve that?

Comment: In JS, to implement and interface means that it has certain properties and methods, usually monkey-patched into the object. To be an instance of something means `obj instanceof Something` is true.

Comment: @elclanrs So you mean it can be `request` is instance of IncomingMessage and it has monkey patched (as you mention) some methods of readablestream?

Comment: I meat duck-typing, but yeah, that's the idea.

Comment: Let me Google that for you :) https://www.webreflection.co.uk/blog/2016/03/23/javascript-interfaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [node.js source for an http incoming message](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_incoming.js), you see this:

```
/* Abstract base class for ServerRequest and ClientResponse. */
function IncomingMessage(socket) {
  Stream.Readable.call(this);
  ....
}
```

and this:

```
util.inherits(IncomingMessage, Stream.Readable);
```

Which shows that an `IncomingMessage` constructor inherits from a `Stream.Readable`.  It also overrides some of the readable methods to modify their behavior.

> How would you achieve that in JS?

You would create your own object that inherits from another.

Comment: ah so `request` is instance of IncomingMessage which inherits from Stream.Readable - and that's it?

Comment: @johna - Yeah, that's basically it.  You can see where the IncomingMessage object is created [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/9f55eac346dea4fba6ace9becc1e01d893f56c5c/lib/_http_common.js#L76).

Answer (score 0):

An object can both "implement" and "be an instance of" something, but the interface is just for documentation purposes.

In JS, to be an instance of something means that `obj instanceof Something` is true.

In dynamic languages, like JavaScript, to implement an interface means the object is expected to have certain methods. This is commonly known as [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

> If an IncommingMessage behaves like a ReadableStream, and can be used as a ReadableStream, then it must be a ReadableStream.

Comment: Except that in the case of an IncomingMessage, it actually inherits from a ReadableStream.  Regular Javascript inheritance.

Comment: Good point. So it's just a prototype chain in this case. I guess conceptually when I read "instance" in dynamic langs I think inheritance, and "implements" I think duck-typing, not necessarily an inheritance chain.